# Android 5.0: how to change recent apps title color?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I'm using AppCompat and my theme is extending `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

When in Android 5 Lollipop and I press the recent apps button, my app appears with a **dark** title instead of a white title in the ActionBar.

When I'm inside the app everything looks fine.

What can I do to change the title color in the recent apps view?

**EDIT**: just figured out that if I use a darker `colorPrimary`, the title becomes white. I still need a way to force the white title with the original color.

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a darker color as colorPrimary, I set the recents color as colorPrimaryDark. Just like the status bar color is darker, recents color is also darker for me and the title became white. I think it is the best way to do it. Thank you for the question and the great app unclouded

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't force the text color, it is auto generated (either white/black) based on your `colorPrimary` color.

Comment: Here's the code in question if you're interested: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/model/Task.java#L147

Comment: I would add that this colorPrimary which affects the color of the text is defined in your app theme as an item. Like: `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>`

Answer (score 39):

I also looked into this and the best way I could find was (suggestion from MrEngineer13) setting my recents app color to the [600-value of my primary color](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), app_icon);
TaskDescription taskDesc = new TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name), bm, getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_600));
MainActivity.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
```

If you look closely at the Android 5.0 contacts app, you can see that Google themselves is also doing something similar:

[image: Screenshot Android contacts]

Therefore I believe it is impossible to change the title color yourself, but Android will choose a good one for you. (which will also allow Android to change it for accessibility reasons,...)

Comment: In spite of I would like to set my own blue, this suit on the app as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This is the **real** answer. I used the "white text" on the palette. For example, Light Blue 600 - #039BE5, the palette shows white label for it on the website.

Answer (score 25):

To change the color/title/icon you just need to use the following:

```
TaskDescription tDesc = new TaskDescription(mTitle, mIcon, mColor);
MainActivity.setTaskDescription(tDesc);
```

Comment: That only allows you to change the background/primary color, not the title. 
It's still useful because I can pick a slightly darker background color and the title automatically becomes white, but I would still like to be able to change the title color directly.

Comment: This article talks about TaskDescription and shows an example https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/polishing-your-Android-overview-screen-entry/

Comment: where do I put this code? In the oncreate of my main activity?

Comment: @Marshall: A good place for this code is in `onResume()`. Just figured out the hard way that it won't work in `onCreate()`.

Comment: can i set `Typeface` for this?

Comment: What about before api-level 21?