# Setting header color and icon of app on Android's recents screen using Titanium/ Alloy/ Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

How do I change the header color in recent apps screen (see below) on Titanium?

[image: Recent apps screen]

A similar question is asked here, but not for titanium:

[Setting header color of app in overview (recent apps) screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079658/setting-header-color-of-app-in-overview-recent-apps-screen)

The reason I ask is that my logo is black, and the taskbar color on mine is dark grey so you can't see it.

Is it also possible to use a different different icon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use themes, you can find it in the documentation how to:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes