# Keep color of appBar when Overview button is pressed

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-appbar

I finish my app, but this is something that I don't find answer. I want to keep the color of appBar when Overview button (android right button - image 1) is pressed. In my app it changes to a different blue.

How can I define this color?

Already tried this way, but didn't work:

```
runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'app',
    home: _defaultHome,
    theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Color(0xFF0C4376),
        ),
    ),
```

[image: Overview button]

[image: Color changed]

Comment: Look into android-specific methods of doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079658/setting-header-color-of-app-in-overview-recent-apps-screen. I _don't think_ (not sure) there is any official flutter support for doing this. Maybe try setting the primary color of the `MaterialApp` before trying android-specific methods?

Comment: You can also try changing the primaryColor in Android resources.  I think it is taking this blue color from Android as mentioned by Christopher

Answer (score 0):

Like Christopher and Sahdeep said in the comments, changing the primaryColor worked. Thanks.

```
runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'app',
    home: _defaultHome,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF0C4376),
    ),
```