# How do I set the android overview screen title and close button color

Tags: android

How do I make my title and X color white regardless of the primary color... Twitter does it..

[image]

Comment: It's automatically computed to maximize contrast. Make your background darker.

Comment: @alanv can u provide more information on this, I want to do a similiar thing. Do they use the new palette for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 5.0: how to change recent apps title color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899820/android-5-0-how-to-change-recent-apps-title-color)

Comment: They don't, since it's in the framework, but palette is the right thing for an app to use.