# Cordova/Android: change app banner color (NOT status bar)

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently using Apache Cordova to experiment with all of it's capabilities. I can't seem to find out how to change the banner that appears when you tap the "view open application" option on android.

**How do I change the color of the banner seen here?**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This question could be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27703228/4241030 , it seems you'll need to change the primary color in the (android folder) res/values/styles.xml

Comment: I don't seem to have a styles.xml file anywhere - in fact the res/ directory has no folder for "values" and color settings don't exist anywhere that I've found within the config.xml.

I opted to use a plugin to change the banner color:
https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor

Comment: of course there should be a folder with the style on it in  {projectname}\platforms\android\res\values-{v14 or the target version}\styles.xml . Awesome, tell me if the plugin works !

Comment: Thanks Carlos! The plugin works perfectly. As for the styles.xml, when the project was generated (in VS) that file and path was not created. Even a quick search for the file outside visual studio comes up blank.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't seem to have any of the files needed to change the banner, so I opted to use a plugin to do this:
https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor

(and it works)

Comment: How did you manage to get this to work? It is not working for me.