# When Minimize the Android app title bar color change

Tags: android, android-layout, ionic-framework, android-applicationinfo

In android 5 and above OS version, when minimize the app

my status bar color is shown in black.

How to i change it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force the text color, it is auto generated (either white/black) based on your colorPrimary color.

[Check link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899820/android-5-0-how-to-change-recent-apps-title-color)